# To hide one Chrome tab

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons

How to hide one Chrome tab, not all, and not pin it of course as it won't hide it ?
Or how create chrome addon (in javascript) to hide one tab ?

Comment: What do you mean by "hide"? How do you want to access the "hidden" tab?

Comment: (Comment for close voters: not a duplicate. That question gives pinning as a solution, this one rejects it. It's unclear what OP wants to achieve.)

Answer (score 0):

If by "hiding" you mean, preventing the tab from using up any memory and preventing it from displaying content, you can install an extension that suspends tabs such as [Auto Tab Discard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-tab-discard/jhnleheckmknfcgijgkadoemagpecfol). It's available for Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Opera. I hope that's helpful!